# Error when backuping exchange 2010 using backup tool in windows server 2008 r2

Tags: exchange-2010

It will come out the below error when backuping exchange 2010 using backup tool in windows server 2008 r2

**Consistency check for component 'e8ed1165-a879-49f4-8865-99a99de6a2ff'\'Microsoft Exchange Server\Microsoft Information Store\servername' failed.**

My company using exchange 2010 (two server installed with windows server 2008 R2).

There is an DAG between two exhange server.

I have sort and find some suggestion on exchange 2007 as per below ,but i not sure that it suit for exchange 2010.

- Open Registry Editor and browse to the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Exchange\Replay\Parameters registry key.

  2. Add a new DWORD value named EnableVSSWriter and set the value to 0 (zero).
  3. Restart the Microsoft Exchange Replication Service.*

Any suggestion? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that registry change applies to Exchange 2010 DAG members when using Windows Server Backup.

http://exchangeserverpro.com/event-id-2137-windows-server-backup-completed-warnings-exchange-2010-mailbox-server